# phpmyadmin mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused

Tags: mysql, connection, phpmyadmin

I have this phpMyAdmin error on Ubuntu 22.04 on WSL2 running in Windows 10:

[image: phpmyadmin error]

Kernel: 5.10.60.1-microsoft-standard-**WSL2**

I have already tried to create a user.

```
CREATE USER 'pallino'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'pallino';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'pallino'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

This wasn't enough. I cannot access via phpMyAdmin and via shell I can access only using sudo.